# Too many if-else statement, any way to refactor it

Tags: java, refactoring

Can this be refactored? or this looks fine. (variable names changed)

```
if (cmpScope.equals(GLOBAL)) {
            return true;
        } else if ((cmpScope.equals(X) || cmpScope.equals(Y))
                && cid == pid) {
            return true;
        } else if (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid != pId) {
            return true;
        } else if (cmpScope.equals(V) && cid == pid) {
            return true;
        } else if (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid == pid && cSubId != pSubId) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: pId and pid (see i and I) is a mystype? Anyway IMHO the code looks ok, no need to squeeze it.

Answer (score 13):

Just combine all expressions with or-operators, since they all return true.

```
return  ((cmpScope.equals(GLOBAL) ||
         ((cmpScope.equals(X) || cmpScope.equals(Y)) && cid == pid) ||
         (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid != pId) ||
         (cmpScope.equals(V) && cid == pid) ||
         (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid == pid && cSubId != pSubId));
```

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many upvotes. It's not readable at all and does not look like a clean code.

Comment: @SergeKuharev In whath way it is not readable? I think it is more readable than separate statements, all with the same return statement. Also instead of a lot of return statements, a single return statement it used (one exit is considered better programming practice). If you know a better way to clean it, please add your own answer.

Comment: Imagine reading your code in one month. Will you remember what is what? What will happen if you need to add more conditions? What will happen if you will need to change existing ones? A single return statement is not considered a good practice. In fact, Martin Fowler(http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) and Uncle Bob say that early returns are good. One exit statement was considered a good practice more than 10 years ago. And of course, I've added my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Code readability is sometimes very subjective; I consider my code more readable than yours (all in 5 lines versus scattered over multiple functions). If there would be some kind of reuse or very complicated conditions, it would be a good idea to use separate functions. I mostly use early return statements for pre-condition checking which is not the case in the above line. Thanks for adding your answer (always good to have alternatives).

Comment: Almost everything is subjective in programming, so it's good to see alternatives - when you have options you think about them and eventually become better. When you blindly follow some rules, you have no chance to become the better developer.

Comment: @Serge Kuharev Fully agree, I have seen many examples of code looking very unreadable because some strict coding conventions had to be used. Also, mostly (due to time reasons but also lack of 'interest', code is never refactored, resulting in a mess soon).

Answer (score 2):

You could store the result of the conditions in variables and handle all conditions in one statement. (Though I don't think that's a better solution in all cases)

```
boolean trueCond1 = cmpScope.equals(GLOBAL);
boolean trueCond2 = (cmpScope.equals(X) || cmpScope.equals(Y)) && cid == pid;
boolean trueCond3 = cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid != pId;
boolean trueCond4 = cmpScope.equals(V) && cid == pid;
boolean trueCond5 = cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid == pid && cSubId != pSubId;

return (trueCond1 || trueCond2 || trueCond3 || trueCond4 || trueCond5);
```

Comment: The (marginal) disadvantage of this approach is that it doesn't use short-circuit evaluation between the various `trueCondX`. It is like replacing the `||` in MichelKeijzers' answer with `|`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of all the `else`s because each `if` clause returns a value.

```
if (cmpScope.equals(GLOBAL)) {
    return true;
}
if ((cmpScope.equals(X) || cmpScope.equals(Y)) && cid == pid) {
    return true;
}
if (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid != pId) {
    return true;
}
if (cmpScope.equals(V) && cid == pid) {
    return true;
}
if (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid == pid && cSubId != pSubId) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This is one of the best techniques for reducing the apparent complexity of code.  Depending on your specific needs, grouping into a single expression with or operators might be a better solution.  Also the cid/pid comparison is common to the last four tests, so something like this might be better still:

```
if (cmpScope.equals(GLOBAL)) {
    return true;
}
if (cid == pid) {
    if (cmpScope.equals(X) || cmpScope.equals(Y)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (cmpScope.equals(V)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (cmpScope.equals(Z) && cSubId != pSubId) {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    if (cmpScope.equals(Z)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

I fully support @carl-manaster response, but I think we can go further.

My approach is based on following principles:

- there should be no else statements.
- complex logical expressions should be extracted into private methods to increase readability.
- there is a test suite that covers all possible branches. This is why people are worried about cyclomatic complexity. And this is why extracting into method helps.

From the example code, it's not clear what exactly does this method, so I picked some random names and the author should change it to something more valid.

I had no tests and no time, so I'm not 100% sure it will work, but after series of changes I've ended up with following code:

```
function(cid, pid, cSubId, pSubId) {
    return cmpScope.equals(GLOBAL) && isValidSomething() && isValidSomethingElse();
}
```

Where extracted methods are:

```
function isValidSomething() {
    if(cid != pid) {
        return false;
    }
    if (cmpScope.equals(V) || cmpScope.equals(X) || cmpScope.equals(Y)) {
        return true;
    }
    return cmpScope.equals(Z) && cSubId != pSubId;
}

function isValidSomethingElse() {
    return cmpScope.equals(Z) && cid != pId;
}
```

It's just an example and you can improve it even more.

Again, the main point of this is to have private methods with good names so that you can read it "like a well-written prose". Imagine this:

```
function isMyCarValid() {
    return isHaveWheels() && isHaveFuel() && isHaveDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the 'return true' is just an example? Otherwise you could group all statements that return true in one expression. If they are actually meant to do different things, that looks fine to me. (In some cases a switch statement can be used, not in this case, but in general it could be good to know that you can use this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)